# Syntax Help: Row with all zeros in an else-if Statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am basically trying to write an else-if statement that filters out a row if the first element of the row is not -1 or if the row is not all zeros. For example,

```
-1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

would both pass through

but `1 0 1 1 1` would not

The portion of code that I have for this is

```
else if (headSetChecked && j!= cols-1) 
{
   if (tempRow[0]!== -1 || tempRow[j]!== 0);
   {
        isScrap=true;
        break;
   }
}
```

I am getting the error C2059: syntax error:'=' om the "if statement". I know my syntax is wrong, but I am not sure what to change it to. "tempRow" is the array that I am going through and filtering out the rows that do not follow the conditions. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
if (tempRow[0]!== -1 || tempRow[j]!== 0);
               ↑                   ↑
```

- Use `!=` and not `!==`
- Remove the `;` after the `if` because it's like writing `if (tempRow[0]!== -1 || tempRow[j]!== 0) {}`, in your case, `isScrap = true;` and `break;` are always executed since your `if` does nothing.

Comment: Wouldn't != make TempRow[0] equal to -1 instead of being a condition to check if it is equal to -1?

Comment: @GCODE No, `!=` **compares** and doesn't **assign**. If you do `=`, that would be an assignment.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks! How long have you been coding in C++? I just started learning about 2 months ago and it is tough.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such operator as !== in C++ as you wrote in the statement

```
    if (tempRow[0]!== -1 || tempRow[j]!== 0);
```

So the compiler splits it in two operators != and = and reports the error.

Also I would like to append that the condition that selects required rows can be written the following way

```
if ( tempRow[0] == -1 || 
     std::all_of( tempRow, tempRow + 5, std::bind2nd( std::equal_to<int>(), 0 ) ) )
{
   // the condition has been satisfied
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't != make TempRow[0] equal to -1 instead of being a condition to check if it is equal to -1?